# How to configure Nginx to change root directory on existence of a particular cookie?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Trying to configure my site to change root directory when there is a cookie var called "developer". This is on a Debian server.

This is my current site config file:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /sites/live/;

    if ($http_cookie ~ 'developer') {

        root /sites/dev/;
    }

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ { 
        try_files $uri =404; 
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
    } 

}
```

But that gives me this error:

nginx: [emerg] "root" directive is not allowed here

What should I be doing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add root inside the location and the condition what you want
following is he my  configuration working fine

```
location / {
    root /var/www/myside;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

if that not work use rewrite rule

Comment: Thanks, not sure I fully understand what you're saying though, do you mean add the IF statement I'm using the detect the cookie after the location brackets? Inside the location brackets but after the root statement?

Can rewrite be used to change the root folder? I thought it just affected urls